# Combine two sed commands in one line

Tags: unix, awk, sed

I'm looking for an `in place` command to change all file lines which end with `:.:.`

From

```
chr01   1453173 .   C   T   655.85  PASS    .   GT:AD:DP:PGT:PID    0/1:25,29:54:.:.
```

To

```
chr01   1453173 .   C   T   655.85  PASS    .   GT:AD:DP    0/1:25,29:54
```

In words, I'm basically deleting `:PGT:PID` and `:.:.` from any line ending with `:.:.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU sed and Solaris sed:

```
sed '/:\.:\.$/{s///;s/PGT:PID//;}' file
```

If you want to edit your file with GNU sed "in place" use option `-i`.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for something like:

```
sed -i.bak "/^.*:\.:\.$/ {s/:PGT:PID//g; s/:\.:\.//g;}" file
```

- it does inplace replace with file and creates a backup as file.bak
- the `/^.*:\.:\.$/` restricts the s command to lines ending in `:.:.` the `.` need quoting because they are special characters for regexes
- the `s` sommand replaces the strings with the empty string

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for the advice, I improved the answer.

Answer (score 1):

With awk that'd be:

```
awk 'sub(/:\.:\.$/,""){sub(/:PGT:PID/,"")} 1' file
chr01   1453173 .   C   T   655.85  PASS    .   GT:AD:DP    0/1:25,29:54
```

and for inplace editing with gawk you could add the `-i inplace` option while with any awk you can just add `> tmp && mv tmp file`.

Answer (score 1):

As a one-liner:

```
sed -i -e '/:\.:\.$/!n' -e 's///' -e 's/:PGT:PID//g' "$file"
```

Expanded:

```
/:\.:\.$/!n     # leave lines untouched unless they end in ":.:."
s///            # replace the matched ":.:." with nothing
s/:PGT:PID//g   # replace ":PGT:PID" with nothing, everywhere
```

We use the `-i` flag to perform in-place edits.  We pass each line as a separate `-e` expression for portability: some sed implementations allow several commands to be concatenated with `;`, but that is not required by the POSIX standard.